# Why is "shut" an adjective in "locked shut"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Definition of 'shut' in Collins English Dictionary.

Shut is also an adjective, with example sentence "**The exit doors were locked shut.**"

I wonder why 'shut' in this sentence is an ADJECTIVE not an ADVERB?

Comment: Because it describes the state of the door, unlike “locked tightly”, where *tightly* describes the action.

Comment: I agree with Lawrence. The adjective "shut" is called a 'predicative adjunct': predicative because it relates to a predicand ("doors") and adjunct because it is a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it is part of the verb phrase "were locked shut", not of the noun phrase subject "the exit doors".

Comment: If this question has been answered, please provide an answer and accept it.